# How to open/run java program using cmd in another java program

Tags: java

I want compile Java program by making a Javac command in cmd using another Java program, then run it. How do I do that? Is there a class that i can use?

for example here is the cmd
    C:\Users\UserName\Documents> Javac HelloWorld.java

How can i compile HelloWorld.java inside a java program, then run it.

Here is my initial source code wherein there is a directory and a Java file.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String directory = "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Documents";
        String fileName = "HelloWorld.java";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't run .java files, they are not executables. Are you perhaps trying to run something already compiled? Or are you trying to run the compiler from within Java as well?

Comment: do you want to run executable .jar files?

Comment: Maybe you want to open the texteditor?

Comment: you can create batch file and run that batch file from java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
try {
    // Execute command
    String command = "cmd /c start cmd.exe";
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    // Get output stream to write from it
    OutputStream out = child.getOutputStream();

    out.write("<execute the java class by mentioning the usual command>");
    out.flush();

    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compile different java files using this a program , you can try this method.

```
public class Laj {

  private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(ins));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(name + " " + line);
    }
  }

  private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
    printLines(command + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
    pro.waitFor();
    System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      runProcess("javac YourDir/HelloWorld.java");
      runProcess("java YourDir.HelloWorld");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("ok");
  }
}
```

Comment: To dynamically compile and load Java classes, better use JavaCompiler.

Comment: I don't believe `javac` should begin with a capital `J`

Comment: here is the error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to compile the other source code first. The Java compiler is actually written in Java itself. You do not need to invoke the javac.exe, instead take a look at `javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()` [ToolProvider Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html).

Once you compiled the source code file with that, you can use the class loader to load the compiler class file and invoke the code from there, probably by means of reflection.

Overall you are asking for an advanced use case.